# Difficult Sketching Complex Number Question

Tags: functions, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Sketch: Re(z) > Arg(z)

I considered the modulus argument form of a complex number:

z = r ($cos{\theta} + isin{\theta})$

from this I got:

r$cos{\theta} > \theta$  $\Longrightarrow$ r > $\frac{\theta}{cos{\theta}}$

I am not sure how to sketch this graph and am not sure where to even start as this came in a paper in our exams.

Comment: Personally, I would not even consider trying to sketch such a graph by hand.  Although (in theory), you could obtain a rough sketch in 30 minutes, (or perhaps less) by manually plotting specific points on graph paper, I regard that as largely a waste of time.  Such a situation is best resolved by [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_graphics_software).  One alternative is [Latex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX), which offers such free graphical plug-ins as Asymptote, PSTricks and PGF-Tikz, among others.  Also, Geogebra (which I have never used) may do the job here.

Comment: See also my comment following the answer of am301.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by looking at two values of $r$, say $r=0$ and $r=10$ of the function
$z=r-\dfrac\theta{\cos\theta}$ and ask in what regions is it positive. It looks like this:
[image]
It is obvious the the periodic part $-\dfrac\theta{\cos\theta}$ changes periodically along the $\theta$ axis and will cross the $z=0$ line at different points according to the value of $r$. As $r$ changes such points will get closer to the zeroes of $\cos\theta$. For $r=0$ only $\theta=0$ crosses the $z=0$ axis. It is then should be easier to understand the 3-d plot:
[image]

Comment: **To the OP**: As an example of what my comment following your question signifies, look at this answer.  Do you really think that these images were *hand-drawn*?